# Can't deserialize json array

Tags: c#, android, json, xamarin, json.net

I know this question has been asked many times. But i'm still a newbie and it seems like I can't deserialize the json array I got from a get request.

This is my code:

**Activity.cs**

```
var getResponse = RequestClass.GetChargingPointsData(pathUrl, currentToken);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("My GETresponse: " + getResponse);

            //CharchingPointClass getCPDetail = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CharchingPointClass> (getResponse);
            //var getCPDetail = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CharchingPointClass> (getResponse);

            //List<CharchingPointClass> getCPDetail = (List<CharchingPointClass>)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(getResponse, typeof(List<CharchingPointClass>));


            CharchingPointClass result = (CharchingPointClass)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(getResponse, typeof(CharchingPointClass));
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("My longitudes: " + result.lat);
```

The codes in comment also didn't work for me...

**CharchingPointClass.cs**

```
public class CharchingPointClass
{

    public string _id { get; set; }
    public double price { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string model { get; set; }
    public string modelID { get; set; }
    public double lat { get; set; }
    public double lng { get; set; }
    public string address { get; set; }
    public int __v { get; set; }
    public string modified_at { get; set; }
    public string created_at { get; set; }



    public CharchingPointClass ()
    {
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:
json**

```
[
{
    "_id": "56d98506a7012ee0001bc42c",
    "price": 135.5,
    "type": "Type2",
    "model": "id11",
    "modelID": "Model1",
    "lat": 15.5,
    "long": 123.56,
    "address": "Van Vaerenberghstraat 11, 2600 Berchem",
    "__v": 0,
    "modified_at": "2016-03-04T15:58:44.142Z",
    "created_at": "2016-03-04T12:52:22.719Z"
},
{
    "_id": "56d98909a7012ee0001bc42d",
    "price": 5000,
    "type": "TypeBart",
    "model": "MijnModel",
    "modelID": "Home-1-ABC",
    "lat": 4.427484,
    "long": 51.197772,
    "address": "Van Vaerenberghstraat 11, 2600 Berchem",
    "__v": 0,
    "modified_at": "2016-03-04T13:09:29.173Z",
    "created_at": "2016-03-04T13:09:29.172Z"
},
{
    "_id": "56d98987a7012ee0001bc42e",
    "price": 22.22,
    "type": "Type222",
    "model": "aaa",
    "modelID": "abc1223456",
    "lat": 4.442229,
    "long": 51.141699,
    "address": "Veldkant 37, 2550 Kontich",
    "__v": 0,
    "modified_at": "2016-03-04T13:11:35.466Z",
    "created_at": "2016-03-04T13:11:35.466Z"
},
{
    "_id": "56d989d0a7012ee0001bc42f",
    "price": 0.17,
    "type": "TypeNG",
    "model": "ModelDeborah",
    "modelID": "ModelIDDeb",
    "lat": 4.418491,
    "long": 51.222212,
    "address": "Osystraat 53, 2060 Antwerpen",
    "__v": 0,
    "modified_at": "2016-03-04T13:12:48.706Z",
    "created_at": "2016-03-04T13:12:48.706Z"
}
```

]

**Error message:**

> {Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'iChargeClassTest.CharchingPointClass' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
>   To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List that can be deserialized from JSON array.JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.}

Can anybody help me out of this please?

Help is very appreciated :)

Comment: What is the Json string you are trying to deserialize?

Comment: What's the issue if that last call functions properly? Does `CharchingPointClass result = (CharchingPointClass)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(getResponse, typeof(CharchingPointClass));
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("My longitudes: " + result.lat);` not work?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the error message and my json. I editted my post

Comment: @ext0 yes it's that line of code that fails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the line for Deserializing.

```
  var result=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CarchingPointClass>>(inputString)
```

Class will be

```
  public class CarchingPointClass
  {
   public string _id { get; set; }
   public double price { get; set; }
   public string type { get; set; }
   public string model { get; set; }
   public string modelID { get; set; }
   public double lat { get; set; }
   [JsonProperty("long")]
   public double lng { get; set; }
   public string address { get; set; }
   public int __v { get; set; }
   public string modified_at { get; set; }
   public string created_at { get; set; }
 }
```

Comment: if I use that line, it won't alow me to get something out of the json. i can't do 'result.lat' for example

Comment: you have to use result[0].lat 
as this is an array.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the following class to serialize to instead.

```
public class CarchingPointClass
{
    public string _id { get; set; }
    public double price { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string model { get; set; }
    public string modelID { get; set; }
    public double lat { get; set; }
    public double @long { get; set; }
    public string address { get; set; }
    public int __v { get; set; }
    public string modified_at { get; set; }
    public string created_at { get; set; }
}
```

Then serialize using the following line.

```
var result=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CarchingPointClass>>(inputString)
```

Comment: It's still not working. I've deserialized a single json object and it got no problem but It won't deserialize the  json because it's in an array. :/

Comment: Ah, you need to serialize it using the following line of code. `var result=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CarchingPointClass>>(inputString)`.

Comment: Yes, you are right Thank you very much for helping me out! :) But as Anik said I needed to add `result[0].lat` to get something out of the json.