# Why JSON response can't be deserialized as List<> even though it's an array?

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net, restsharp

First of all, sorry for the long and maybe redundant question. I admit that I've seen a similar question, but I have honestly tried all the solutions, but it didn't solve my problems. I code using .NET in C#, with Newtonsoft and RestSharp as my Nu-Get packages, and I'm trying to retrieve data from Wordnik API.

This is how the JSON looks:

```
[
  {
    "id": "A5530700-1",
    "partOfSpeech": "interjection",
    "attributionText": "from The American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, 5th Edition.",
    "sourceDictionary": "ahd-5",
    "text": "Used to show encouragement or approval to a boy or man.",
    "sequence": "1",
    "score": 0,
    "labels": [],
    "citations": [],
    "word": "attaboy",
    "relatedWords": [],
    "exampleUses": [
      {
        "text": "Attaboy! That's the way to hit a home run!"
      }
    ],
    "textProns": [],
    "notes": [],
    "attributionUrl": "https://ahdictionary.com/",
    "wordnikUrl": "https://www.wordnik.com/words/attaboy"
  },
  {
    "partOfSpeech": "interjection",
    "attributionText": "from Wiktionary, Creative Commons Attribution/Share-Alike License.",
    "sourceDictionary": "wiktionary",
    "text": "Used to show encouragement or approval to a boy or man.",
    "labels": [
      {
        "text": "idiomatic",
        "type": "usage"
      },
      {
        "text": "colloquial",
        "type": "register"
      }
    ],
    "citations": [],
    "word": "attaboy",
    "relatedWords": [],
    "exampleUses": [],
    "textProns": [],
    "notes": [],
    "attributionUrl": "http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/",
    "wordnikUrl": "https://www.wordnik.com/words/attaboy"
  }
]
```

This is the problematic part of my code:

```
        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

        var resultArray = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ResultsDefinition>>(response.Content);
        string wordDefinition = resultArray[0].Text;
```

and this is a my ResultsDefinition class:

```
public class ResultsDefinition
{
    public string ExtendedText { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string SourceDictionary { get; set; }
    public List<Citation> Citations { get; set; }
    public List<Label> Labels { get; set; }
    public float Score { get; set; }
    public List<ExampleUsage> ExampleUses { get; set; }
    public string AttributionUrl { get; set; }
    public string SeqString { get; set; }
    public string AttributionText { get; set; }
    public List<Related> RelatedWords { get; set; }
    public string Sequence { get; set; }
    public string Word { get; set; }
    public List<Note> Notes { get; set; }
    public List<TextPron> TextProns { get; set; }
    public string PartOfSpeech { get; set; }
}

public class Citation
{
    public string Cite { get; set; }
    public string Source { get; set; }
}

public class Label
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}

public class ExampleUsage
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

public class Related
{
    public string Label1 { get; set; }
    public string RelationshipType { get; set; }
    public string Label2 { get; set; }
    public string Label3 { get; set; }
    public List<string> Words { get; set; }
    public string Gram { get; set; }
    public string Label4 { get; set; }
}

public class Note
{
    public string NoteType { get; set; }
    public List<string> AppliesTo { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public int Pos { get; set; }
}

public class TextPron
{
    public string Raw { get; set; }
    public int Seq { get; set; }
    public string RawType { get; set; }
}
```

Everytime I tried to run my code in VisualStudio, it always give me Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException. Which, to my understanding, is because the JSON is somehow being read as a JsonObject and not JsonArray.

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35816096/cant-deserialize-json-array) that I need to put the inputString to the JsonConvert.DeserializeObject parameter, but I already did right (since I write 'response.Content' in my code)?

This is the exact exception I get:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ConsoleAppTest.ResultsDefinition]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.

Do you have any suggestions to fix this?

Comment: What exact exception are you getting? Please post it too

Comment: Are you sure `response.Content` is string? If it is a object, you wont't be able to Deserialize it directyly

Comment: I can't reproduce this.

Comment: @AdritaSharma I'm not sure. Maybe not, since I keep getting exception when I run my code. What string is supposed to put into the JsonConver.DeserializeObject parameter? I don't get that part.

Comment: @Voodoo My bad, I edited my question

Comment: Just hover the mouse over the `response.Content` to know the type of `Content`. It needs to be `string`

Comment: @Voodoo yes, it's string. It still won't work

Comment: The parameter to the deserialize method should be the string containing the json.

Answer (score 0):

Working well with me.

Look at this sample.

[image]

https://dotnetfiddle.net/tZfHaZ

What is `response.Content` data type?

If you use a double quote as a wrapper, make sure you escape attribute value with backslash `\"`.

If you use a single quote as a wrapper, make sure you escape attribute value with backslash `\'`.

Comment: I just checked and response.Content is supposed to be string. It still won't work for me. Is this somehow has to do with the API I'm trying to retrieve data from?

Comment: @AlexandraWinastwan I think there are double quotes inside your property value try to escape it with backslash `"` -> `\"`

Comment: @AlexandraWinastwan how the API handle double quote inside property value? could you show us sample data with double quotes that exists?

Comment: Sorry, I'm a beginner and I don't really get what you mean? The JSON code I included in my question is the result I get when I try to access my API URL in my browser.

Comment: @AlexandraWinastwan Did you make the API yourself? or it's publicly available?

Comment: It's publicly available, called Wordnik API

Comment: Hmm... No Issue with the API https://i.imgur.com/d2IUSrB.png . Did you use Add Web Reference or Add Service Reference?

Answer (score 0):

If `response.content` is not string, then try this:

```
var responseString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response.content);
var resultArray = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ResultsDefinition>>(responseString );
```